# How to pass Images from html page to .aspx page?

Tags: html

```
<input type="file" name="Browse" id="imgfile1" size="50" value="" />

//Image Image1 =Convert.ToBase64String(Request.Form["Image1"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload an image using an `<input type="file" />` tag.

Additionally, the form tag should have a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute for this to work (as described in the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3)).

What you are doing now, is passing in text to the server side. So, unless this is a text encoded version of the contents of the image file, it will not work.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) is an (somewhat old) article about uploading files in asp.net.

Comment: @test - If you don't take care with your questions, how is anyone supposed to give you a useful answer?